# $scope issue. Changes not been displayed in HTML view

Tags: javascript, angularjs, scope, jstree

*Guys I am new to Angular and I am facing a bit of a problem :*

Now I am using ngJsTree and I am overriding the "selectNodeCB" method which simply does something when you select a node from the tree. It looks like this in my controller :

```
$scope.test = "Hellow World"
...
function selectNodeCB(event, data) {
        debugger;
        $scope.test = "Goodbye World";

}
```

Now when I select a node in the UI we stop on the debugger. The $scope.test is changed to "Goodbye World" and nothing more. After the method is finished no changes are display to the UI (HTLM vieiw).

I believe it has something to do with the none $scope looking of the "selectNodeCB" function because when I do this:

```
$scope.testFnc = function () {
        $scope.test = "Goodbye World";
};
```

and I set it on-click on some button it works perfectly. Also I tried calling the "testFnc" from the "selectNodeCB" it executes but nothing changes again ofcourse in the HTML.

I am sure that I am forgeting something really obvious so if someone can give me a tip I will be very glad.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Good ppl I have found the answear it was a problem in the HTML view :

```
            <div class="portlet-body">
                <div class="container" ng-controller="EditPrizeTableCtrl as vm">
                    <div class="row" cg-busy="vm.promise">
                        <toaster-container></toaster-container>
                        <div class="col-xs-6">
                            <div class="panel-body">
                                <div id="ptTree" js-tree="treeConfig" should-apply="ac()" ng-model="treeData"
                                     tree="treeInstance" tree-events="ready:readyCB;select_node:selectNodeCB"></div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
            ......
            <div> {{test}} </div>
```

Now the solutions is this : If the {{test}} is outside the container

```
<div class="container" ng-controller="EditPrizeTableCtrl as vm"> ... </div>
```

It does not work. If you put the {{test}} inside :

```
<div class="container" ng-controller="EditPrizeTableCtrl as vm"> {{test}} ... </div>
```

Works fine. But this is not a general solution. So you can just not make the variable "vm" and just use "EditPrizeTableCtrl " where you need it in the container :

```
         <div class="portlet-body">
            <div class="container">
                <div class="row" cg-busy="EditPrizeTableCtrl.promise">
                    <toaster-container></toaster-container>
                    <div class="col-xs-6">
                        <div class="panel-body">
                            <div id="ptTree" js-tree="treeConfig" should-apply="ac()" ng-model="treeData"
                                 tree="treeInstance" tree-events="ready:readyCB;select_node:selectNodeCB"></div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
        ......
        <div> {{test}} </div>
```

That way it works perfect !